# Явный и неявный вызов функции в ООП?

Tags: ооп, терминология

Вызов метода *явный* (*explicit*) и *неявный* (*implicit*), чем они отличаются?
Если я правильно понимаю, явный это что-то вроде:

```
obj.meth(x, y);
```

Что в таком случае будет не явным вызовом?
И какие методы нельзя вызывать явно?

Comment: Возможно, это вызов функции по указателю на неё? (Не уверен, т. к. не знаю.)

Comment: Вызов по указателю? Есть вызов по ссылке и вызов по значению. Вызов по указателю - не знаю.

Comment: В scala, например, может вызваться неявный метод преобразования, если хотя бы один аргумент не подходит под сигнатуру метода. Но не уверен, что вы имели в виду это.

Comment: @Etki, да, этот пример отлично подходит.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin: Вы программировали когда-нибудь на C?

Comment: В Java при конкатенации строки для нестроковых типов *неявно* вызывается `.toString()`. Т.е. компилятор делает это за вас.

Comment: @VladD, вызов функции через указатель на нее, в любом случае, не имеет отношения к неявному вызову.

Comment: @VladD на C - не явно. На objective-c - явно. (в смысле программировал)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам пример: в PHP есть "магический" метод `__toString`, реализуя этот метод в классе, мы указываем как экземпляр класса должен предствить себя в виде строки (string). Когда объект класса с определенным методом `__toString` вызывается в контексте, который предполагает, что работа идет со строкой, то неявно вызывается магический метод `__toString`, перед выполнением других действий над объектом.

```
class SomeClass {

    public function __toString() {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }

}

$a = new SomeClass();
echo $a; // outputs 'Hello World!'
```

В строке с `echo $a;` сначала неявно будет вызван метод `SomeClass::__toString()`, хотя мы явно и не давали такой инструкции, а затем будет исполненно `echo`.

Можно привести еще много примеров из разных языков, но я думаю, что основная идея должна быть понятна.

**UPD**

Явный вызов методов - простите за тафтологию, Вы явно указываете в своем коде, какой метод и с какими аргументами Вы хотитите вызвать. Неявный вызов - компилятор (или интерпретатор) делает это за Вас неявно. 
На C++ давно ничего не писал, поэтому к сожалению не могу привести пример неявного вызова метода, но вспомнил, наверное, самый известный и простой для понимания пример "неявного" в C++ - это `this`, указатель на экземпляр класса, все функции-члены класса в C++ (кроме статических) *неявно* принимают в качестве аргумента указатель на экземпляр класса, в контексте которого происходит обращение к методу.

Comment: а можете привести примеры из java или C? А то не очень понятно пока что.

Comment: И знаете ли вы примеры методов (такие наверняка есть в некоторых языках) которые нельзя вызвать явно? Тоже очень важная составляющая. И всё равно спасибо, плюсую, уже начинает доходить.

Comment: На Си давно не писал, сейчас попробую вспомнить или найти примеры и сделаю апдейт ответа.

Comment: На С - не надо. Он не ООП. Может на С++ или Objective-C?

Comment: получается, к примеру приведение типов - это тоже не явный вызов метода?

Comment: если приведением типов занимается компилятор (или интерпретатор), да.